# TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that accepts the types defined in A as an argument, but I want to make the typing more restrictive so I created B.

```
interface A {
    readonly x: any;
}

interface B extends Omit<A, 'x'> {
    readonly x: number;
}
```

The problem is, this function won't accept the types in B, even though it's more restrictive than A. Instead I get the error `No overload matches this call`, saying that `Type(props: B) => number is not assignable to type (props: A) => number"`.

This function also won't accept `props: { x : number }`, giving me a similar error message.

Comment: Can you share a complete example? The code snippet does not give an error by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that function arguments are [contravariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance). And their assignability is checked in the reverse direction compared to normal value types assignability. That's why you cannot assign a function accepting limited subset of values to the function accepting much wider set of values:

```ts
interface A {
    readonly x: unknown;
}

interface B extends Omit<A, 'x'> {
    readonly x: number;
}

declare function narrowerFn(props: B): number

const widerFn: (props: A) => number = narrowerFn // errror
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wO8a7N)

It makes a perfect sense. Since the target side function can accept for example a string that source side function doesn't know how to deal with.

But it perfectly works in the opposite direction:

```ts
interface A {
    readonly x: string;
}

interface B extends Omit<A, 'x'> {
    readonly x: number | string;
}

declare function widerFn(props: B): number

const narrowerFn: (props: A) => number = widerFn
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLR9bw)

Since now the target side function can accept only a subset of values the source side function can deal with perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not need `Omit`. Just override the property as follows:

```
interface A {
    readonly x: any;
}

interface B extends A {
    readonly x: number;
}
```

Also, I've created the following example to highlight the problem:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=57#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20VCOAEwHsQAbAT2QA8AuZOESgbiwF8stRJZEUAQsgg1IIIgGc0mHHgLEyVWgxABXALYAjaG05YwlAA4oAYugC8yABSGoJQxIaoAlMnMA%20ZGq06uB48gmQpY2dg4MAq4eXhraUGxYCGQSYMgwmgxBbtYYtMjsUZ40yADUyACMCUkgKWlwmRZpmgkA9C3IAKo1cDAoqhJwAOYQADTICHD9KOnCNMYIYFLecRJjICSpKVCggxKJySTkEAB05CSDVvBWufTIAOTld-nOzizIbcgA8qpghj-IACJyuUAchQClCERkCQYMgAExYIA)

```
type FA = (props: A) => number;

type FB = (props: B) => number;

const fb: FB = ({ x }) => x + 1;

const fa: FA = fb;

// Unsafe usage, cause fb expects numbers, not strings
console.log(fa({ x: '1' })); // Output "11" instead of 2
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of contravariance but the point of `Omit` as used in the question is to define an interface extending a type that is not the type containing the broader definition of `x` such that inheritance isn't violated. The error is coming from a function which isn't included in the question.

Comment: You should post that on the question.